# Front camera capture while the screen is blank

Tags: android, android-camera, android-2.2-froyo

I wish to use the front camera of a device to capture the image without any preview and the screen to remain blank.
I have a way to remotely activate this but not sure how to do it.
I found this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10702906/showing-blank-screen-while-recording-video-in-motorola-attrix-2-with-android-2-2.
It is pretty close to what I want but I'm not sure how to use the code and change it to camera.